# Troubleshooting audio for Acer Aspire E 17 (E5-771G-7868)

Tags: sound, lubuntu, alsa, acer, aspire

My system is `Lubuntu 14.04.1 AMD64 Desktop`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux polyphemus 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Sound is not playing:

```
$ speaker-test

speaker-test 1.0.27.2

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

These are my devices:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
```

The modules are loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
snd_hda_intel          56451  1 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69322  13 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
```

What else could I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default soundcard is HDMI device, not main soundcard .
A way to change sound devices order at a low level (alsa) is to add this 2 lines at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf :

`options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=auto vid=8086 pid=9c20`
`options snd-hda-intel index=1 model=auto vid=8086 pid=0a0c`
then reboot.

(the "vid" and "pid" value is from your  lspci command)

You could find other way like using pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control)  to change default output device for Pulseaudio: clic green buton near second device in "output device tab", not sure it will works for speaker-test .